# android - SwipeRefreshLayout - обновление свайпом ВВЕРХ

Tags: android

Очень хороший виджет `SwipeRefreshLayout` позволяет что-то делать при прокрутке сверху. Как сделать чтобы он также выплывал сверху но при свайпе в конце `ListView`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867204/swiperefreshlayout-pull-from-bottom

Comment: https://github.com/OrangeGangsters/SwipyRefreshLayout

Comment: и еще очень много других готовых решений вы можете найти в гугле https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=Android+swipe+to+refresh+from+bottom